# Sticky selection box

Tags: php

I am trying to write a sticky selection box using HTML and PHP. I want the selections the user entered before submit to be highlighted after submit is pressed. I have tried a couple different ways and it does not seem to work. Here is the line as I have it now.

```
<select name="selectBox[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
<?php 
$i=0;

while($temp=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
{
    //echo $temp[1];
?>  
    <option value="<?php echo $temp[1] ?>"
        <?php if(isset($_POST[$temp[1]])) {echo "selected";} ?> >
        <?php echo $temp[1] ?> </option>

<?php   
    $i++;
}

?>
</select>
```

I know that the `echo "selected"` works because I have tried it with just that in the option tag.

Here is the whole code with a slightly different option tag within the selection tags but it still does not worry.

```
<html>
<head><title>Business Registration</title></head>

<body>
<h1>
Business Registration
</h1>



<?php

$user="*********";
$DBserver="localhost";
$password="*********";

$myDatabase='nedwards';
$myTable1='categories';
$myTable2='businesses';
$myTable3='biz_categories';

//connect to the database server.
$con=mysql_connect($DBserver,$user,$password);

$con or die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());//check connection

mysql_select_db($myDatabase) or die("Unable to select database");//select the databse we will be using
                                                                //check selection

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $myTable1");//gets the category table.... we will use the fetch_array and take the 2nd element of the array for select box

$submitted=$_POST['submitted'];

if($submitted)
{

    $sql="INSERT INTO $myTable2 (name, address, city, telephone, url) VALUES ('$_POST[bis_name]', '$_POST[addr]', '$_POST[city]', '$_POST[tele]' , '$_POST[url]')";
    mysql_query($sql, $con) or die('Error dude: ' .mysql_error());



//  echo "$_POST[bis_name]";
//  echo "$_POST[addr]";
//  echo "$_POST[city]";


    $chosenTitles=$_POST[selectBox];

    //echo "$_POST[bis_name]";

    foreach ($chosenTitles as $temp)//will run through each title chosen
    {
        //echo "$temp";//for testing

        //get cat id
        $catTitle2IDtemp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $myTable1 WHERE title='$temp'", $con);
        $catTitle2ID=mysql_fetch_array($catTitle2IDtemp, MYSQL_NUM);
        $catID=$catTitle2ID[0];//this is the category ID

        //get biz id
        $temp=$_POST[bis_name];
        $bis_name2IDtemp=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $myTable2 WHERE name='$temp'", $con);
        $bis_name2ID=mysql_fetch_array($bis_name2IDtemp, MYSQL_NUM);
        $bizId=$bis_name2ID[0];//this is the biz ID


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO $myTable3 (business_id, category_id) VALUES ('$bizId', '$catID')");

    }




}



?>


<table border="1">


<tr>
<td rowspan="5">
<form name="input" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"> 


<select name="selectBox[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
<?php 
$i=0;


while($temp=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))//gets each row of categroy table "$result" and takes second element of array $tempto select box
{
    //echo $temp[1];
?>  




    <option value="<?php echo $temp[1] ?> "    <?php if(in_array($temp[1], $chosenTitles)){echo "selected";}   ?>        > <?php echo $temp[1] ?>   </option>


<?php   
    $i++;
}

?>
</select>

</td>

<td>Buisness Name</td> 
<td>    <input type="text" name="bis_name" value="<?php if($submitted==1){echo $_POST['bis_name'];}?>"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address</td>    
<td><input type="text" name="addr" value="<?php if($submitted==1){echo $_POST['addr'];}?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>City</td>   
<td><input type="text" name="city" value="<?php if($submitted==1){echo $_POST['city'];}?>"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Telephone</td> 
<td><input type="text" name="tele" value="<?php if($submitted==1){echo $_POST['tele'];}?>"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>URL</td>    <td><input type="text" name="url"  value="<?php if($submitted==1){echo $_POST['url'];}?>"  /></td>  
</tr>


<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

</table>

<input type="Submit" value="Add Business"      />
</form>





<?php 
$submitted="0";
$_POST['submitted']="0";
?>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful for you to cut the code sample down to eliminate lines that you're pretty sure are irrelevant to this particular issue.

Comment: the top part is the relevant section with the bottom being the whole page in case someone wanted to see the overall picture. Specificaly the <option tag

Answer (score 3):

You can use in_array php function.

Below is some sample code which will guide you.

```
<? 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $selectBox = $_POST['selectBox'];
    }
?>
<form name="input" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post"> 
<select name="selectBox[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
<option <? if(in_array('one',$selectBox)){ echo 'selected';}?> value="one">one</option>
<option <? if(in_array('two',$selectBox)){ echo 'selected';}?> value="two">two</option>
<option <? if(in_array('three',$selectBox)){ echo 'selected';}?> value="three">three</option>
<option <? if(in_array('four',$selectBox)){ echo 'selected';}?> value="four">four</option>
</select>

<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Add Business"/>
</form>
```

Comment: have tried using the in_array function and it does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it right

```
<option value="<?php echo $temp[1] ?>"
    <?php if(isset($_POST[$temp[1]])) {echo "selected";} ?> >
    <?php echo $temp[1] ?> </option>
```

produces

```
<option value="some value"selected> some value </option>
```

To specify that an `option` should be selected you need to use the `selected` attribute:

```
<option value="some value" selected="selected"> some value </option>
```

Try this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $temp[1] ?>"
    <?php if(isset($_POST[$temp[1]])) {echo ' selected="selected"';} ?> >
    <?php echo $temp[1] ?> </option>
```

Comment: whether it is echo selected or echo selected="selected it does not work. It seems like it is not getting the value of $temp[1]. echo selected works for the purpose I am using it for but I know the correct way is the way you purposed.

Comment: @aaron burns: Then that should be your question. You commented out `echo $temp[1];` -- what did that do, and have you tried `print_r($temp);`? What's the purpose of `$i`?